# Create new matrix in R by summing rows of another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

So I have the following matrix (let's call it output):

```
> output

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] 
[1,]   1    1    1    0    0    1
[2,]   1    1    1    0    0    1
[3,]   1    1    1    0    0    1
[4,]   0    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]   1    0    1    1    0    0 
[6,]   1    0    1    1    0    0
```

What I want to do is to create a new matrix (output2) by adding rows in groups of two. For example the first row of the new matrix would be:

```
output2[1,] <- output[1,] + output[2,]
```

The second row of the new matrix output2 would consist of the sum of the third and fourth row of the old output matrix:

```
output2[2,] <- output[3,] + output[4,]
```

And so forth. I was wondering what is the best way to code this, considering I will need to do the same to bigger matrices. I was considering creating dummy variables with the seq() function and maybe a for loop.

Is there a simpler way?

Edit:

> dput(output)

structure(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 19L))

Comment: please post `dput(yourMatrix)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `m` is your matrix, try this:

```
m[seq(1,by=2,to=nrow(m)),]+m[seq(2,by=2,to=nrow(m)),]
```

Comment: Yes, I think that works for what I had in mind! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

These both:

- handle both even and odd numbers of rows
- generalize to k rows by replacing 2 with k
- are short -- one line of code or could easily be made one line
- (1) uses only base functions, i.e. no packages and (2) can be readily generalized to functions other than sum.

**1) rowsum** Use `rowsum` with a second argument of `c(1, 1, 2, 2, ..., 5, 5)` which is readily created using `gl`:

```
nr <- nrow(output)
rowsum(output, gl(nr, 2, nr))
```

**2) rollapply** Another possibility is to use rollapply from zoo.  If we knew that the number of rows was even we could optionally omit the align and partial arguments.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(output, 2, by = 2, sum, align = "left", partial = TRUE)
```

Comment: Both are working fine! But the rollapply() seems a bit slower. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use vector recycling:

```
matrix(output[c(TRUE, FALSE)] + output[c(FALSE, TRUE)], ncol = ncol(output))
```

Comment: This solution also works for me. Thanks for the help!